# Mongoose/MongoDB increasing twice and I can't figure out why

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am creating a query to increase something by 1, but for some reason the query runs twice:

NEW CODE: (deleted old code) However, I went away from async because I thought that was causing it, it is not. I am not sure what is causing it but here is what I am doing now:

```
socket.on('upgrade-stat', data => {
  const args = {
    id: socket.handshake.session.passport.user
  };
console.log('Snapshot Start');
  Snapshot.updateOne(
    { userid: args.id },
      {
        $inc: {
          'stats.str': 1
        }
      }
     ).then((res) => {
       console.log('Snapshot done');
     });
  console.log('Start increment query');
  User.updateOne(
    { _id: args.id },
    {
      $inc: {
        'currency.cs': 1
      }
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  ).then(user => {
    console.log('End increment query');
    return 'It worked';
  });
});
```

I took the liberty of enabling debugging for mongoose and here is what this produces in my console:

```
Snapshot Start
Start increment query
Mongoose: users.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cd49529b7809f44e48f84ed") }, { '$inc': { 'currency.cs': 1 } }, {})
Mongoose: snapshots.updateOne({ userid: '5cd49529b7809f44e48f84ed' }, { '$inc': { 'stats.str': 1 } }, {})
Mongoose: users.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("5cd49529b7809f44e48f84ed") }, { '$inc': { 'currency.cs': 1 } }, {})
Snapshot done
End increment query
```

I would like to point out its doing this after passport login and deserializing. The login process only runs one query. Doing queries after that using events from the client to always double up.

EDIT: Further investigation it seems to only be doubling up on the User model and nothing else. Using a different model it works fine, I am not sure whats causing this because there is no difference here.

Comment: please reduce your code for understand

Comment: What is calling the method that you're showing here? It is possible that the business logic is correct here but you're calling the method multiple times, eh?

Comment: Reduce it how, everything there is needed. And it shouldn't be the method calling it, otherwise the console.logs would double up. Its only the increment getting doubled, nothing else is.

Comment: I shortened the code and included the method call